# How to connect two LG 27UD88 to single thunderbolt 3 port

Tags: display, thunderbolt, 4k

I have late 2016 MacBook Pro 13, which has thunderbolt 3 and according to specification can chain two 4k monitors. So if that's correct, how would it be possible to connect two LG 27UD88 monitors over single cable?

I suspect I need some hub that will input thunderbolt 3 and output 2 USB-C as that's what this monitor supports.

Also if this would work, will charing work too?

So basically I want to plug two monitors with a single cable and the same time chard my Mac.

Thanks.

Comment: An almost duplicate of [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/5g42s5/can_you_daisy_chain_usbc_monitors_to_a_macbook/?st=IYSV16NG&sh=f6d1346a) that basically says yes. You can do this. Only if you have 2 thunderbolt monitors. USB-C display port doesn't.

Comment: bret7600, you are right, that's what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @Dimitry Did you succeed in daisy-chaining two LG 27UD88 monitors? I'm considering buying a second one and it would be nice if I just could connect the second one to the first one without having to connect two USB-C cables in my MacBook Pro 15" (2019) every time. Thanks!

Comment: @splattne unfortunately no, I think that will not work. Monitor is USB-C, so you can't chain it, it would work only for thunderbolt type monitors. Additionally I have another problem with second monitor that I almost never use. In most cases my mac is not able to wake up if two monitors are connected and only complete reboot helps. I've struggled so much with this setup so highly disappointed in this generation of macs and not using second display.

Comment: @Dimitry Thanks, yes in the meantime I read a lot about it and I understand the problem. Thinking about getting a Dock where which I can plug in/unplug using a single cable